# The Monsey Karfif

Tags: halacha, eruv-chatzerot

The [Monsey/Rockland Eruv map](http://www.rocklanderuv.org/pages/map.php) indicates one large *karfif* (in red). A karpef/karfif is as an area not designated for residency which invalidates an encompassing eruv if it is not itself separated by a distinguishing barrier and is greater than 5000 square *amoth* (~10,000 sqft.; see e.g. [here](http://rabbikaganoff.com/do-people-live-in-the-zoo/))  However, the Rockland eruv seems to be filled with many such wooded and unused areas (e.g. [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Rockland+County,+NY/@41.1551786,-74.0428731,528m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c2c9caf11a7127:0x1f98163a4a0f684e!8m2!3d41.1489458!4d-73.9830029), [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Rockland+County,+NY/@41.1475356,-74.0504379,540m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c2c9caf11a7127:0x1f98163a4a0f684e!8m2!3d41.1489458!4d-73.9830029), [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Rockland+County,+NY/@41.1470063,-74.0953762,535m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c2c9caf11a7127:0x1f98163a4a0f684e!8m2!3d41.1489458!4d-73.9830029), etc.) or lakes (e.g. [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Visions+Vcb/@41.1577105,-74.0490833,18.05z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x89c2c9caf11a7127:0x1f98163a4a0f684e!2sRockland+County,+NY!3b1!8m2!3d41.1489458!4d-73.9830029!3m4!1s0x0:0xd17b2f4744af2642!8m2!3d41.1576441!4d-74.046654), [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Rockland+County,+NY/@41.13491,-74.0483947,273m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c2c9caf11a7127:0x1f98163a4a0f684e!8m2!3d41.1489458!4d-73.9830029), [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Rockland+County,+NY/@41.1220406,-74.0596666,18.02z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c2c9caf11a7127:0x1f98163a4a0f684e!8m2!3d41.1489458!4d-73.9830029), etc.).  So what distinguishes the demarcated *karfif* from these other uninhabited areas?

Comment: Great question, you can email Rav Yosef Viener (choshuv Rav in Monsey) through his publicly available shiur site : Yv@torahstream - dot- org

Comment: They prob rely on different Kulas, like on a lonely dilapidated shack that can make the Karpef into a Hukef ledirah. Or if they are recreational areas according to R Moshe they can be included in the Eiruv. see "The laws of Eruv"  by shlomo francis and yonason glenner, pp. 153-155. I don't know what the case in Monsey, in particular, is though.

Comment: @bach I'm pretty sure a lot of these are just large, unused and undeveloped areas of woods, etc.